# Compare two strings in extended memory - classic 8052

Tags: performance, strings, validation, assembly, embedded

I'm looking for a simpler code that isn't resource hungry that can compare two strings stored in different locations in the extended memory of a classic 8052 (namely the AT89S52 microcontroller) to make sure the characters match exactly.

The error flag can be a bit value, but the only thing that concerns me is that I need scanning to begin at any two 16-bit memory locations of my choice and that the same number of consecutive bytes in each location need to be scanned.

I was considering applying boolean logic to DPH or the DPL variables (example ANL and ORL) but at the same time will I be able to make that programmer friendly? I don't want to make the memory addressing confusing later on. Also, I'm looking for code that can replace this that can provide better performance (meaning fewer instructions required to execute a string comparison code).

Any ideas are welcome.

```
;Load # bytes to check in R7
mov R7,#BYTESTOCHECK

;R6 = our error status. Assume no error here
mov R6,#0h

;Load first memory pointer address to R2:R3
mov R2,#HIGHBYTE1
mov R3,#LOWBYTE1

;Load second memory pointer address to R4:R5
mov R4,#HIGHBYTE2
mov R5,#LOWBYTE2

checknextbyte:

  mov DPL,R2
  mov DPH,R3
  ;DPTR here = R2:R3
  movx A,@DPTR
  ;Store value at DPTR in B
  mov B,A
  inc DPTR
  mov R3,DPH
  mov R2,DPL

  mov DPL,R4
  mov DPH,R5
  ;DPTR here = R4:R5
  movx A,@DPTR
  ;Store value at DPTR in A
  inc DPTR
  mov R5,DPH
  mov R4,DPL

  CJNE A,B,notsame
    ;Both addresses aren't same so string isn't same
    ;make R7=1 to exit loop faster
    mov R7,#1h
    ;Make R6=1 to show we have error
    mov R6,#1h
  notsame:

djnz R7,checknextbyte
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `AT89S52` is not a classic `8052`. Like all modern 8052 variants I know of, it has one feature which really shines here. Namely, it is dual data pointers. Instead of reloading `DPL` and `DPH` every time, initialize them once, and just toggle the `AUXR1.DPS` bit:

  ```
  ; setup
      clr AUXR1.DPS
      mov DPL, R2
      mov DPL, R3

      cpl AUXR1.DPS
      mov DPL, R4
      mov DPL, R5
      ....

  ; loop
  checknexbyte:
      cpl AUXR1.DPS
      movx A, @DPTR
      mov B, A
      inc DPTR

      cpl AUXR1.DPS
      movx A, @DPTR
      inc DPTR

      cjne mismatch
      djnz R7, checknextbyte
  mismatch:
  ```
- You may spare a register (`R6`), few cycles, and some bytes by using `C` flag (set by `CJNE`) as a match/mismatch indication.
- It looks like the exit logic is incorrect. On a mismatch (`A != B`) the jump *is* taken, and the loop continues. Correct me if I am wrong.